# Can IIS log the sub domain part of the url?

Tags: iis, logging, iis-7

I have a website served by IIS. Logging is turned on and i get infrmation like:

`2013-02-26 00:23:16 ::1 GET /Test/TestPage.html <snip>`

But I have a subdomain per customer so that a.mydomain.com and b.mydomain.com both point (via CNAME) at the same installation and serves the same files (but I have code that shows different data).

What I'd like is to be able to say that customer a hit the website x times and downloaded y but and customer b hit it z times (etc).

But the a.mydomain.com doesn't seem to be logged and doesn't look like I can turn it on.

Is it possible to get this information?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can enable that by opening IIS Manager, clicking in Logging, then "Select Fields" button and choose Host (cs-host).

If you want the command line version would look something like:

```
%windir%\system32\inetsrv\appcmd.exe set config -section:system.applicationHost/sites /siteDefaults.logFile.logExtFileFlags:"Date, Time, ClientIP, UserName, SiteName, ServerIP, Method, UriStem, UriQuery, HttpStatus, Win32Status, TimeTaken, ServerPort, UserAgent, Referer, Host, HttpSubStatus"
```

Note that this will change it for all sites (since its modifying the siteDefaults section), but you could make it apply only to a specific site if desired.

Comment: Unfortunately ths doesn't work because of the CNAME redirection - it only givess the final host (which in my case is xxx.cloudapp.net because I'm hosting on Azure). Thanks for your answer though!

Comment: that should not be the case, the host should be the header provided by the client (in the host header) which means you should see the original one entered in the browser. I run my site in Azure and indeed I get the right host name in the logs when logging host.

Comment: D'oh! You're right! I took an example log from our test server. Turns out the BA usually goes to the cloudapp address. I took a log from PROD and the information is there. Thanks!